# Nginx rewrite rules for SEO friendly URL structure - WordPress and another Web application

Tags: php, html, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have got WordPress installed on my root example.com/ Website.

Also I have another Web application that on example.com/my-app/ which has got ugly links like example.com/my-app/file.php?arg=value to access.

How can I make my-app SEO friendly URI structure working as example below?:

```
example.com/my-app/file.php?arg=value
to
example.com/my-app/value/
```

Currently, if I access to example.com/my-app/value/ it redirects me to my WordPress post which contains some characters of the /value/. Why? Is there anyway to get this working?

My Nginx directives for domain are listed below:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Any ideas? Should I use Ajax navigation, with switch cases? What about HTML5 pushState() API? Any working examples?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both WordPress and `my-app` work within a common document root which makes things simple.

The last element of the `try_files` directive is the default action for (for example) SEO friendly URLs.

You need a different default handler for URIs which begin with `/my-app`, which is achieved using a `location /my-app` block, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location /my-app {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /my-app/file.php?arg=$uri&$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

In the above case, `arg` is set to the value `/my-app/value`. If you really must extract the last part of the URI, add a named location with a rewrite, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location /my-app {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/my-app/(.*)$ /my-app/file.php?arg=$1;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

Note that the `fastcgi_read_timeout 300;` (in your question) needs to be placed in the `location ~ \.php$` block, or in one of the outer blocks, in order to be effective.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for details of the `nginx` directives used above.