# How to send response to a URL, where page dose not exits?

Tags: php, apache, http

I am Creating a URL shortning service with core php, I created a Database storing long and short (generated after submission of the form) URL's. Is there any way i can make it like this that i dont have to use a page to acess the short URL, Let me explain in detail.

- I have a `index.php` and it has a form, it takes a URL or long URL from the user and after validation of the URL i save the Long Url with a short 5-6 character string, i save this to my database, and i will send back the short URL to the User.
- To acess the short URL i created another page called `link.php` and i am listining for the querystring in this page request like this `http://localhost:80/link.php?q=d3432hnc`.

#### Ans i am looking for this question  -

So i am asking that is there any other way i can acess the short url just like `https://localhost:80/jfkdasjfkajsd` without making a page and passing this url in the queryStrings like `http://localhost:80/link.php?q=jfkdasjfkajsd`.

Comment: What you ask is not related to PHP. To achieve that you have to configure your HTTP server to accept pretty URLs and drive the requests to your PHP files. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273756/nginx-rewrite-rules-for-seo-friendly-url-structure-wordpress-and-another-web-a depending on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Search for "php URL rewriting".

You can setup Apache or nginx to rewrite the first url into the second.

Comment: IMHO this does not really give an answer, but suggests how to find one.

Answer (score 0):

look into `mod_rewrite` module and .htaccess of apache/php

In essence, it allows treating URL segments as parameters and passing them to a script

.htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
ReWriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now if your website is called by an URL http://website.com/this/is/great

index.php gets invoked and URL segments are passed via GET parameter

In `index.php` you can use:

```
$url = explode('/', htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']));
```

to get an array of URL segments. Use them to figure out what file to return